# install vagrant in ubuntu ?

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant

I am using ubuntu 14.04.

```
apt-get install vagrant
vagrant ssh


This Vagrant environment has specified that it requires the Vagrant
version to satisfy the following version requirements:

  >= 1.8

You are running Vagrant 1.4.3, which does not satisify
these requirements. Please change your Vagrant version or update
the Vagrantfile to allow this Vagrant version. However, be warned
that if the Vagrantfile has specified another version, it probably has
good reason to do so, and changing that may cause the environment to
not function properly.
```

but going to the https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html, I can find any downloads related to ubuntu.

how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu has the very old version of Vagrant installed. You're better off just downloading and installing the package from [Vagrant downloads](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html) page you linked.

It cleanly installs in Ubuntu 14.04 with:

```
sudo dpkg -i vagrant_1.*_x86_64.deb
```

And you can easily remove it with:

```
sudo dpkg -r vagrant
```

In fact, vagrant package for Debian from downloads page works cleanly on most other Linux distros (I've tried it on Gentoo also).

Comment: Just verified that this also works for Ubuntu 16.04.